# How do I mock and test MaterialUI - makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm trying to add a better testing coverage for my React components, and one of the places I cannot mock is the inside of this

```
export const useTabStyles = makeStyles(({ options: { common } }) => ({
>>>  root: ({ size }: TabProps) => ({
    '&&': {
      fontSize: size === 'MD' ? common.fonts.sizes.p3 : common.fonts.sizes.p,
    },
  }),
}));
```

When I check the code coverage, is saying that the `>>>` line is not being checked.
I've tried to have something like this

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@material-ui/core/styles'),
  makeStyles: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.fn()),
}));
```

but then I'm not sure, how to check whether the given line was called with `size = MD or LG`.

Here is the code for `it`

```
it('should render normal style', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Tab size="MD" />);
    // how do I mock check here whtehr the makeStyles received the proepr size.
  });
```

Comment: If you still want an answer, I just found the Perfect way to mock `makeStyles`, with direct `jest.mock` or manual mock config. This solved all 4 main problems: 1- undefined theme, 2- Normal Test Coverage, 3- Advance Test Coverage when passing parameters inside useStyles and receiving them in makeStyles function property, 4- `useStyles()` error when mocking `React.context` messes up with `makeStyles` function result that uses `React.context` internally.

Comment: @KeitelDOG there is no accepted answer here, so you should put it here as an answer.

Comment: @user1713450 I think you're right. I just added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking `makeStyles` with simple jest function make you loose test coverage. When making it more complex, it leads to some problems, and each problem solved leads to another:

- it lost test coverage when calling useStyles which is now an empty function with no style (`const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {...})`)
- Not mocking it throw error for additional values of a custom theme
- Binding mocked function argument with the custom theme works, and you can call function argument to fill coverage. But you loose coverage if passing parameters when calling `useStyles({ variant: 'contained', palette: 'secondary' })` (result function of makeStyles)
- Lot of things broke when mocking useContext, because makeStyles result function uses useContext internally.

(example of useStyles parameter handling)

```
{
  backgroundColor: props => {
    if (props.variant === 'contained') {
      return theme.palette[props.palette].main;
    }
    return 'unset';
  },
}
```

I managed to solved all of these problems and use manual mock https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks:

**Step 1:**

I mocked in the core path instead, but both should work: `<root>/__mocks__/@material-ui/core/styles.js`

```
// Grab the original exports
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import * as Styles from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import options from '../../../src/themes/options'; // I put the theme options separately to be reusable

const makeStyles = func => {
  /**
   * Note: if you want to mock this return value to be
   * different within a test suite then use
   * the pattern defined here:
   * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks
   */

  /**
   * Work around because Shallow rendering does not
   * Hook context and some other hook features.
   * `makeStyles` accept a function as argument (func)
   * and that function accept a theme as argument
   * so we can take that same function, passing it as
   * parameter to the original makeStyles and
   * bind it to our custom theme, created on the go
   *  so that createMuiTheme can be ready
   */
  const theme = createMuiTheme(options);
  return Styles.makeStyles(func.bind(null, theme));
};

module.exports = { ...Styles, makeStyles };
```

So basically, this is just using the same original `makeStyles` and passes it the custom theme on the go which was not ready on time.

**Step 2:**

`makeStyles` result uses `React.useContext`, so we have to avoid mocking `useContext` for makeStyles use cases. Either use mockImplementationOnce if you use `React.useContext(...)` at the first place in you component, or better just filter it out in your test code as:

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(context => {
  // only stub the response if it is one of your Context
  if (context.displayName === 'MyAppContext') {
    return {
      auth: {},
      lang: 'en',
      snackbar: () => {},
    };
  }

  // continue to use original useContext for the rest use cases
  const ActualReact = jest.requireActual('react');
  return ActualReact.useContext(context);
});
```

And on your `createContext()` call, probably in a `store.js`, add a displayName property (standard), or any other custom property to Identify your context:

```
const store = React.createContext(initialState);
store.displayName = 'MyAppContext';
```

The makeStyles context displayName will appear as StylesContext and ThemeContext if you log them and their implementation will remain untouched to avoid error.

This fixed all kind of mocking problems related to makeStyles + useContext. And in term of speed, it just feels like the normal `shallow` rendering speed and can keep you away of `mount` for most use cases.

**ALTERNATIVE to Step 1:**

Instead of global manual mocking, we can just use the normal `jest.mock` inside any test. Here is the implementation:

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles', () => {
  const Styles = jest.requireActual('@material-ui/core/styles');

  const createMuiTheme = jest.requireActual(
    '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme'
  ).default;

  const options = jest.requireActual('../../../src/themes/options').default;

  return {
    ...Styles,
    makeStyles: func => {
      const theme = createMuiTheme(options);
      return Styles.makeStyles(func.bind(null, theme));
    },
  };
});
```

Since then, I also learned to mock `useEffect` and calling callback, axios global interceptors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening on the coverage side is that the function being tested, the hook `useTabStyles` is the result of `makeStyles` fn, which accepts as input a callback, which is the one missing the coverage because it does not get executed following your mock.

If you change your mock in this way, this should also execute that code which will be then cover:

```
makeStyles: jest.fn().mockImplementation(callback => {
  callback({ options: { common: { fonts: { sizes: {} } } } }); // this will execute the fn passed in which is missing the coverage
  return jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ // here the expected MUI styles });
}),
```

You can also anyway ignore the coverage checks of that fn simply adding before the following line:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
export const useTabStyles = makeStyles(({ options: { common } }) => ({
  root: ({ size }: TabProps) => ({
    '&&': {
      fontSize: size === 'MD' ? common.fonts.sizes.p3 : common.fonts.sizes.p,
    },
  }),
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Great catch there, the only thing I was missing for full coverage. THIS SHOULD BE ACCEPTED ANSWER. I manual mocked makeStyles globally, created the theme on the go and bound it to the original makeStyles because the custom theme wasn't ready in Hook at some places. I caused a lot of failures at some tests. The only way now is to call the callback function passing the created theme as parameter, and BOOM: No Crash and Full Coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same issue so I resolve that issue like that I hope it's helpful for others as well.

Thanks

This is my style file

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   root:{
       backgroundColor: theme.common.white,
   }
}));
```

Here is my Component

```
import { useStyles } from './ExampleStyles';
const Example = ({ children }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
       <div className={classes.root}><h4>Hello world!</h4></div>
    );
};
export default Example;
```

Now here is the test case.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Example from 'shared/components/Example';
import theme from 'shared/utils/theme';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Example Component', () => {
    const props = {};
    it('Should render Example component', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Example {...props} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
        expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('Example Component snapshot testing', () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const tree = renderer
            .create(
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Example {...props} />
                </ThemeProvider>,
                div
            )
            .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

I just use ThemeProvider for the accessing theme variable inside html

Comment: That's a very good way of doing it. But the problem is when it comes to do this multiple times in many tests, then Mount is taking too much time for Top level components, and most people want to stay away and use Shallow instead, that will require to mock some Material UI functionalities to work with Shallow rendering. But if the project is not large, then Mount is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

what about extracting it into a function and test it separately?

Comment: btw you can also ask your colleagues..so they can reply to you outside of stackoverflow :D